# Send email as HTML is not working. Why?

Tags: c#, html, .net, email

I have this code:

```
string email = "myemail@gmail.com";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, "mypassword");
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(email, toEmail);
mailMessage.Subject = title;
mailMessage.Body = message;
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

client.Send(email, toEmail, title, message);
```

My message is:

```
message = "hello <b>world</b>."
```

When I recieve the email, it display the `<b>...</b>` not making it bold!

What's wrong with it?!

Comment: have you tried wrapping your message with html and body tags ?

Comment: Just another question, but have you checked whether your client accepts html?

Comment: You aren't actually sending your `mailMessage`.

Comment: @SLaks: it should be an `ANSWER`

Comment: @SLaks Wow, good catch, no one noticed it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You create a `mailMessage` variable holding your HTML-formatted message, but then you ignored it and sent the body as plain text.

You need to send the `mailMessage` itself.

Answer (score 5):

Your message is not a valid html.

Enclose your message with html and body tags

```
message = "<html><body>hello <b>world</b>.</body></html>"
```

Also thanks to @SLaks to point that out

In your sample, you should send mailMessage and not message:

```
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: i don't think its required.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I'm pretty certain it's not required.

Comment: No such overload exists.

Comment: this doesn't make difference.

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH =D

Comment: Thanks to all, no compilation errors this time. If you're saying that is html, then you really should send a valid html. Html clients are pretty lame in terms of what they receive and interpret. So quality html means better message output.